# Can I terminate a process gracefully before the hard eviction with a prestop hook?

Tags: go, kubernetes, apache-zookeeper

My Application stops gracefully when receiving a SIGTERM. graceful-stop operation is deleting a znode in the ZooKeeper.

But what I try is to automatically terminate a process gracefully before the Kubernetes evicts my pod.

I want to set prestop hook to "kill 1" to make a graceful-stop before the pod is evicted.

I'm not expecting prestop hook will work in all cases, but I think, this way I'll have some assurance.

I wonder if my idea is feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `preStop` is possible - and covers your use case. Here's the [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/) example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: lifecycle-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: lifecycle-demo-container
    image: nginx
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
      preStop:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh","-c","nginx -s quit; while killall -0 nginx; do sleep 1; done"]
```

Comment: If the pod doesn't execute a prestop hook when hard-evicted, does Kubernetes sends SIGKILL right away without SIGTERM? If not, I also want to know what's the benefits of SIGTERM in the prestop hook, if it has any.

Comment: `preStop` is very important if you are running a DB etc. and want to prevent corruption as pods are taken offline. Instructing your container to shutdown cleanly - flushing any disk caches etc - is always more desirable than risking a hard exit.